# ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException

Tags: linq

I have a SQL table called Apuntes: 
codigo (PK)
nombre
Proveedor (FK)
Materia
Costo
Precio
Stock Minimo

I got this code on mi LINQ DAL Layer:

```
public static Apuntes UpdateByCodigo(Apuntes LLevarDatos)
{
    Apuntes Update = (from u in db.Apuntes
                      where u.Codigo.Equals(LLevarDatos.Codigo)
                      select u).FirstOrDefault();

    //Update = LLevarDatos;
    Update.Nombre = LLevarDatos.Nombre;
    Update.Proveedor = LLevarDatos.Proveedor;
    Update.Materia = LLevarDatos.Materia;
    Update.Costo = LLevarDatos.Costo;
    Update.Precio = LLevarDatos.Precio;
    Update.StockMinimo = LLevarDatos.StockMinimo;

    db.SubmitChanges();

    return Update;
}
```

and in my Winforms Layer:

```
string CUITPK = DAL_Apuntes_Stock.BuscaCUIT(cmbProveedor.Text).CUIT;
Apuntes LlevarDatos = new Apuntes();

LlevarDatos.Codigo = txtCodigo.Text;
LlevarDatos.Nombre = txtNombre.Text;
LlevarDatos.Proveedor = CUITPK;
LlevarDatos.Materia = cmbMateria.Text;
LlevarDatos.Costo = txtCosto.Text;
LlevarDatos.Precio = txtPrecio.Text;
LlevarDatos.StockMinimo = Convert.ToInt32(txtStockMinimo.Text);

DAL_Apuntes_Stock.UpdateByCodigo(LlevarDatos);

MessageBox.Show("OK", "info");
```

the error I am receiving is

```
ForeignKeyReferenceAlreadyHasValueException in the following line:

LlevarDatos.Proveedor = CUITPK;
```

Anyone have any ideas on this?

Comment: Can you post your `Apuntes` class in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to assign the entity, not just the value.

Something like the below:

```
//Assuming your Proveedor foreignKey is a string and not an int
LlevarDatos.Proveedor = yourDataSource.Proveedor.Single(x.Id == CUITPK);
```